# How can I turn off ViteJS's Hot Module Reload?

Tags: nuxt.js, vite

I have a server side rendered `production` mode Vite application. My issue is that: routinely the webpage will reload and the console will display `[vite] connecting...`. I traced this back to the hot module reload portion of vite's codebase. However, I do not want `hmr` on for `production`, but it still seems to be on regardless of me setting the two settings below to `false`:

In my `vite.config.js` file I have:

```
...
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    hmr: false,
  },
```

Also in my NodeJS `server.js` file I have:

```
const vite = await createViteServer({
  server: { middlewareMode: 'ssr', hmr: false },
})
```

How can I turn off Vite's `hmr`?

Comment: server: { hmr: { overlay: false } }

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `app.js` file:

```
if (import.meta.hot)
import.meta.hot.accept(() => import.meta.hot.invalidate())
```

and in your `vite.config.js` file add `false` to `'defineConfig'`:

```
server.hmr.overlay property
    defineConfig({          
        server: {

            /*here*/
            hmr: { overlay: false }

            }, ...
      })
```

Comment: It's important to not just post the question, but to also include a description of what the code or question does and why you are suggesting or asking it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the question, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question. @Deubledee.

Answer (score 0):

Vite has a [HMR API](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-hmr.html) that allows you to invalidate modules during a reload. You might also be interested in [HMR Server Config](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-hmr) which can be configured in your `vite.config.ts` file.

```
// index.ts
if (import.meta.hot) {
    import.meta.hot.accept(() => {
        import.meta.hot.invalidate();
    })
}
```

Vite also had a `--no-hmr` flag for disabling hot module reloads.

```
vite --no-hmr
```

Unfortunately, both these solutions didn't work for me. Which is why I added the following code to my main/index file for forcing the browser to reload after HMR took place.

```
// index.ts
if (window['reload']) window.location = window.location;
window['reload'] = true;
```

Alternatively, you can add the following plugin to your `vite.config.ts` if you wish to full reload instead of hot module reload.

```
{
    name: 'full-reload',
    handleHotUpdate({ server }) {
        server.ws.send({ type: "full-reload" })
        return [];
    }
}
```