# Disable auto reload vite reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vitest

My application requires a very extensive loading for certain functions, but vite updates the page by itself causing the loading to restart and lose all the progress already made on the page, I would like to know how to disable vite's auto reload.

```
vite.config.ts:

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 5173, // This is the port which we will use in docker
     // Thanks @sergiomoura for the window fix
    // add the next lines if you're using windows and hot reload doesn't work
    hmr: { overlay: false }, 
    watch: {
       usePolling: true
     }
  }
 })
```

Comment: If you're referring to disabling the hot reload maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548801/how-can-i-turn-off-vitejss-hot-module-reload).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable HMR entirely by adding the following to your `vite.config.ts` file.

```
// vite 4.4.9
server: {
    hmr: false
}
```

You might also be interested in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129675/6692685) for forcing the browser to do a full reload on module changes.